# Proper way to use Route alongside Context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-context

I know how to use Routes. I know how to use Contexts. I do not know how to use them together.

I have an application with Routes

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<div/>} />
        </Routes>
    )
}
```

I create a Context and attempt to wrap it around a Route

```
export const Context = createContext(7)

function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Context.Provider value={7}>
                <Route path="/" element={<div/>} />
            </Context.Provider>
        </Routes>
    )
}
```

I get the error

```
Error: [undefined] is not a <Route> component. 
All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

I have not been able to find a simple generalized answer on how to properly use Context in conjunction with React Router, but examples I've seen do not involve using `<React.Fragment>` as suggested in the error message.

Comment: I think your issue is not from the context, it comes from react-router-dom. Routes read the Route and returns component in the element props. But, the context interfere mapping Route. I recommend you to the **Provider** wrap the Routes or use it as element={<Provider><div /></Provider>}

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "provider" component to wrap the context and make use of the `Outlet` component provided by react-router.

```
const NumberContext = createContext(7);

// Create a provider to handle the outlet from the router.
// You can either pass in the value as a prop (like in this example),
// or calculate the value for the context within the component.
const NumberProvider = ({ value, children }) => {
    return (
        <NumberContext.Provider value={7}>
            <Outlet />
            {children}
        </NumberContext.Provider>
    )
}

const App = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            {
                // This provider will wrap all sub routes using NumberProvider's 
                // children prop.
            }
            <NumberProvider value={1}>
                <Routes>
                    {
                        // This provider will wrap all sub routes using NumberProvider's 
                        // contained Outlet prop.
                    }
                    <Route path="/admin" element={<NumberProvider value={2} />}>
                        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<div>Dashboard</div>} />
                        <Route path="/orders" element={<div>Orders</div>} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/home" element={<div>Home</div>} />
                </Routes>
            </NumberProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

In the above example **/home** would find the context that wraps all of the routes and retrieve a value of 1, while **/admin/dashboard** and **/admin/orders** would find the context created by the parent route and retrieve a value of 2.

UPDATE:

You could also do this directly on the `Route` component.

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <NumberContext.Provider value={1}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route 
                        path="/admin" 
                        element={
                            <NumberContext.Provider value={2}>
                                <Outlet />
                            </NumberContext.Provider>
                        }
                    >
                        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<div>Dashboard</div>} />
                        <Route path="/orders" element={<div>Orders</div>} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/home" element={<div>Home</div>} />
                </Routes>
            </NumberContext.Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Comment: Okay, this works and I appreciate it, but is there really not a simpler way available out of the box? The React devs didn't want to provide an official way to use Context alongside Router?

Comment: Providers are not an uncommon practice to wrap single or multiple contexts that may have extra calculations done before creating the actual `Context.Provider`s, it's not to far out of the way to slap an `Outlet` component alongside the `children` prop. This could also be done inline on the `Route` component's `element` prop for simple contexts but as a personal preference I prefer to keep my route elements as a single 
 self terminating component.